# Is the category of Yetter-Drinfeld modules abelian?

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras, abelian-categories

Is $YD(H)$ the category of Yetter--Drinfeld modules over a Hopf algebra (defined over a field $k$) necessarily abelian? If not then what is the simplest example of a Hopf algebra $H$ for which $YD(H)$ is not abelian?

Comment: Yes it is. Braided, monoidal and abelian.